# Getting ClassCastException while typecasting for cutom field in guidewire pc

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I have added a new filed called WebAddress_Ext in Contact.etx file.
After this I have validated the changes and restarted the server.

Now in ContactNameInputSet.company.pcf file I have added new InputText field and for value filed I've given the newly added WebAddress_Ext filed.

```
id = webAddress
label = "Web Address"
value = (contact as Company).WebAddress_Ext
```

Now I tried reloaded the page, then I'm getting the ClassCastException.

```
ClassCastException:entity.Person cannot be cast to entity.Company
```

I have checked that for the fields Primary Email and Secondary Email of Contact.eti they are using  the below code to display the value.

```
id = PrimaryEmail
label = "Primary Email"
value = (contact as Company).EmailAddress1
```

We are not getting any error for PrimaryEmail, but why I'm getting ClassCastException error for new filed called WebAddress_Ext.

Answer (score 3):

While reloading the page in UI, the contact maybe typeof Person. So the contact can not be casted to company if its type is "Company".